# How I can pretty call the edit funcion in react + this.props.onContactSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core

i have some problem with react, i want to edit contact from contactList but i all the time error Uncaught TypeError: this.props.handleContactEditSubmit is not a function...

```
var ContactBox = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return { data: [] };
},
loadContactsFromServer: function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
    console.log(this.props.url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        this.setState({ data: data });
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.send();
},
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadContactsFromServer();
    window.setInterval(this.loadContactsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
},
handleContactAddSubmit: function (contact) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('name', contact.name);
    data.append('phoneNumber', contact.phoneNumber);
    data.append('adress', contact.adress);
    for (var pair of data.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
    console.log(this.props.submitUrl);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('Post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        this.loadContactsFromServer();
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.send(data);
},
handleContactEditSubmit: function (contact) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('id', contact.phoneNumber);
    data.append('name', contact.name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('Post', this.props.editUrl, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        this.props.loadContactsFromServer();
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.send(data);
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="contactBox">
            <h1>Contacts</h1>
            <ContactList data={this.state.data} editUrl="/contact/edit" handleContactSubmit={this.handleContactEditSubmit} />
            <ContactForm onContactSubmit={this.handleContactAddSubmit} />
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

I want to edit contact from this class:

```
var Contact = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return { name: '', id: this.props.id };
},
handleNameChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
},
rawMarkup: function () {
    var md = new Remarkable();
    var rawMarkup = md.render(this.props.children.toString());
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
},
handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.state.name.trim();
    var id = this.state.id;
    if (name == '') return;
    this.props.onContactSubmit({ name: name, id: id });
    this.setState({ name: '' });
},
render: function () {
    var md = new Remarkable();
    return (
        <form className="contact" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Your name"
                   defaultValue={this.props.name}
                   onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </form>
    );
}
});
```

But i displaying this Contacts like a list of contacts and i think this is problem, i don't know how to inherit funcion: handleContactSubmit.

```
var ContactList = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var contactNodes = this.props.data.map(function (contact) {
        return (
            <Contact name={contact.name} id={contact.contactId} key={contact.contactid} onContactSubmit={this.handleContactSubmit}>
                {contact.phoneNumber}
            </Contact>
        );
    });
    return (
<div className="contactList">
    {contactNodes}
</div>
    );
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call handle inside the Contact class and it's working now.

```
 var ContactList = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            var handle = this.props.handleContactSubmit;
            var contactNodes = this.props.data.map(function (contact) {
                return (
                    <Contact onContactSubmit={handle} name={contact.name} id={contact.contactId} >
                        {contact.phoneNumber}
                    </Contact>
                );
            });
            return (
        <div className="contactList" handleContactSubmit={this.handleContactEditSubmit}>
            {contactNodes}
        </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your functions to your component first or the `handleSubmit` function would be bound to the form:

```
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

normally it is done in the constructor

You can also skip the binding if you call the function like that:

```
onSubmit={ function(event) { return this.handleSubmit(event); } }
```

PS: i checked the wrong part of your code, but the issue is still the same. You need to bind the function to your component first:

```
this.handleContactEditSubmit = this.handleContactEditSubmit.bind(this);
```